# Difference between mounting approaches

Tags: linux, mount, systemctl, systemd-mount

As far as I know, there are 3 ways to mount a filesystem in Linux.

1. using the mount command
2. writing a unit file and then activating it with systemctl
3. using systemd-mount

Can anyone please explain to me what are the differences and cons and pros of each?

Comment: Check out the man pages: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd-mount.1.html

Comment: They achieve the same effect

Comment: Use the one that is simplest for you to use under the restrictions given to you by your setup.

Comment: @Peschke There is a line in SYSTEMD.MOUNT(5) : "In general, configuring mount points through /etc/fstab is the preferred approach." the reason I asked the question in the first place is that I don't get why is /etc/fstab the preferred approach

Answer (score 3):

/etc/fstab is the classic (= pre-systemd) way to configure your mount command. In other words, to define mountpoints that you can mount by using a shorter syntax.

Without /etc/fstab (without a entry), you have to write (in shell or script):

```
mount -t spc_fs /dev/exmpl /mnt/point  ro
```

But if you put this info in fstab, it suffices to enter

```
mount /mnt/point
```

That is the 5th syntax variation that `mount --help` shows.

Mounting filesystems starts with the kernel/initrd mounting `root=` and "ends" with removable devices getting automatically mounted, and tmpfs (ramdisks) being created at any time. Plus the loop device for mounting files...

Now, systemd parses /etc/fstab itself, I read somewhere in the man pages, and since it is written in C it uses a library call and not the mount command. And it also takes care during bootup to mount things at the right time. This is systemd core business.

And after bootup, systemd-udevd does the hot-plugging of removables.

So I would rather say there  are two ways "to mount":

1. mount command
2. systemd

Both can be configured and extended, through /etc/fstab in the first place.

---

As to which "approach" to choose: nobody really can say!

If you have systemd correctly installed as a user, you don't need to mount yourself at all. Bootup und udevd is in the hands of systemd. And a user does not even have to loop mount a iso image. He only knows when he sticks in his USB, it appears under /media/usb.

If you want to explore - if Linux forces you to be sysadmin - then just go ahead with systemd. ".mount" is one of the special units. It promises "**control and supervision**" of "**file system mount points**".

And you can always mix. Maybe you want systemd to  mount a "ram disk" at bootup in your home dir. But you can any time create (another) one, under any dir/mountpoint with the command `mount -t tmpfs none dir`.

With just a few GBs on your disk you can install a test Linux with sysvinit instead of systemd. The way you ask you should do it. Me I am 50% for and 50% against systemd. I TRY to get along with sysvinit and very simple scripts. I mount /proc and /sys at bootup and with usb-storage module I at least get /dev/sdb which I then mount, sometimes to pre-defined mointpoints in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I'm still a little confused about why editing /etc/fstab is the preferred approach? As you mentioned entries in /etc/fstab get parsed by systemd (it **generates relevant unit files** for them), and one can simply write a unite file for the mounts. There is also a **systemd-mount** command and the simple **mount** tool, which is preferred for the mounts that are not needed at every boot?

Comment: I am using systemd only recently. I was away from Linux a long time, and now this big discussion about systemd. With /etc/fstab and "mount approach" you are touching holy ground, so to say. You should try and rely on systemd for bootup and hotplug (udevd), Any other mounts (loop mount an iso image) you do by hand, without fstab. --- "...and the simple mount tool"?? I just overlooked systemd-mount, it says it is like the lower-level mount COMMAND. Don't make something cplx even more!  :-)

Comment: I tried to add some general ideas at the end.../etc/fstab "is preferred" because it works for systemd and mount and everybody knows it. It is the system wide "file system table". Nothing really technical.